# How to filter and count certain date log file in current directory?

Tags: unix

I trying to find a count of log file in current directory for certain date(example date:10 oct 2014). I don't know the grep command for that and how to count.please anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
grep -c "10 oct 2014" blah.log
```

To learn more about grep parameters, just enter "man grep" in google. This works fine for all unix/linux commands.